# Pressing on a button causes UIScrollView to scorll

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uibutton

I'm having an inconsistent problem where sometimes I press on a button inside the scrollview. The scrollview catches the event and scrolls instead of the button getting the touch event.
Any idea how to solve this bizarre behavior.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't move your finger while it's pressed down on the button.  If you move your finger at all, the scrollview will cancel the touches sent to the button and process them itself.  It must do this so that you can scroll by touching anywhere on the scrollview, not just an empty space.